# Start a specific program on the Ctrl-Alt-Delete desktop

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to run a specific program on the Ctrl-Alt-Delete desktop.

Our internal developers have created a program that they want the users to have access to BEFORE logging in. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you could get a program to run on that desktop then it could intercept anything typed into the username and password box. Stay clear of the security nightmare!!

Comment: Sometimes we are asked to implement bad ideas

Comment: I'm thinking the answer is no.  I'm also thinking that if you were to enable Tablet PC mode, the keyboard shown on the login screen lives *somewhere* (`C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe`?) and with enough hacking could be replaced  by something that isn't a keyboard.  Of course, in Tablet PC mode this "keyboard" would pop up all over the place at the wrong times, so the answer is probably still no.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible -- the Cisco VPN client does this with it's Start Before Login feature. The Stack Overflow crowd might have more details, but you might try looking for documentation on the "Pre-Login Access Provider" or PLAP feature in Windows Vista and later. I believe Windows XP uses a different method to allow this functionality with something called "Graphical Identification and Authentication" or GINA.